# Thymeleaf check box checked using two string collection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, checkbox, thymeleaf

I have two string collection.

One is to generate all check boxes.

The other one is to select the element to check.

For example, I have two string collections
["A", "B", "C", "D"]
["A", "C"]

I want to make 4 check boxes A, B, C, D
and want to check A and C

I tried as below.

```
    <span th:each="interestName : ${allInterest}">
        <span th:each="interest : ${userInfo.interestName}">
            <input type="checkbox"
               name="eachUserInterest"
               th:value="${interestName.name}"
                th:checked="${interestName.name.equals(interest)}"/>
            <label th:text="${interestName.name}"></label>
        </span>
    </span>
```

However, above code generates a check box repeatedly as many times as it is checked.
[Execution Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFQRR.png)

Help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just loop over the `allInterest` array, and use `contains` to determine whether or not the checkbox is checked.  Something like this for example:

```
<th:block th:each="interest: ${allInterest}">
  <input type="checkbox"
         name="eachUserInterest"
         th:value="${interest}"
         th:checked="${userInfo.interestName.contains(interest)}" />
  <label th:text="${interest}"></label>
</th:block>
```